# How to identify DOM objects for the form attached in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

[image: My sample form]

In JavaScript when I click the Add button, it should first identify the object in the Fax # column, and then execute a jQuery or a masking form for the number  displayed.

As soon as I press the Add button, it should give me the object from that text box and then execute the jQuery?

How do I do that?

```
var advancedtoolbar_additionalfax = new Object();

advancedtoolbar_additionalfax.addfax = function (){

try {
        alert('hi');

        var status = document.getElementById('input');

        for (i = 0; i < status.length ; i++)
        {
        jQuery(function($){
        $('#maint_iframe').contents().find("#additionalfax_faxnumber_0").mask("(999) 999-9999");            
                    });
                }   

        return true;
    } catch ( exception ) {alert(exception)} 
}
```

Comment: Do you have some HTML and basic javascript in a fiddle?

Comment: Added the basic Javascript

Comment: Don't get it. Does this code even work?  So if you press the add button you want to add a new row to that table? And by default the fax column should have the focus with an applied mask?

Comment: Yes, Pardon me I am new to javascript 
so when I press Add button, it should first identify the Fax # column object and while entering the number it should mask the number in format (999) 999-9999

So far the code is giving object error, and I am trying to find out where it breaks down

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your HTML and javascript to http://jsfiddle.net/ and share that?

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Why are you looping and applying a mask to the same element `status.length` times? Do you really have an element with an id of `input`, or, are you trying to get all `<input/>` elements? Also, it's nonsensical to me that you wrap the code inside your loop within a `jQuery(function($) { ... })` block. Why are you doing that?